# MySql SELECT using AND without excluding results

Tags: mysql, database

```
user: ID | FIRSTNAME | 
       1 | JOHN      | 
       2 | JANE      |

category: ID |  CATID   | USERID (which is user ID)
          70 |    1      |    1 
          70 |    6      |    1 
          70 |    5      |    1 
          71 |    2      |    1
          72 |    3      |    1
          72 |    1      |    2
          72 |    2      |    2
```

I currently using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE catid = 1 AND catid = 2 AND catid = 6
```

The above query will return empty because, although JOHN (user id 1) has catid 1,2 AND 6 he also has catid 6. If I use OR it will return JOHN and JANE.

How should I phrase my query to get users with categories 1,2 **AND** 6, even if the user has other categories?

Comment: Your query returns null because it is imposible for catid to be 1, 2 and 6 at the same time

Comment: The user JOHN has several categories associated with his record. This is a rule in the system that only users with a certain group of categories my be selected. But the query with an AND will exclude users with others categories (event when including the right ones)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward way is to do a self join, that is, join the table with itself, once for each value you want to find. This will match only the user that has all 3 values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname 
FROM user u
JOIN category c1
  ON u.id = c1.userid AND c1.catid = 1
JOIN category c2
  ON u.id = c2.userid AND c2.catid = 2
JOIN category c3
  ON u.id = c3.userid AND c3.catid = 6
```

Since this will be a bit messy if you have a dynamic number of values to search for, you may instead want to find the rows that match any of the three values and check that there are three distinct results found;

```
SELECT firstname
FROM user u
JOIN category c
  ON u.id = c.userid
WHERE catid IN (1, 2, 6)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid) = 3
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/137efa/1)

Comment: Thanks @Joachim! I had to make some changes, because my DB was a little different. But it worked perfectly! I used the second query up to the WHERE IN clause, it gave be the result I needed. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurance of the categories and see if the number is 3

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `CATID` INTEGER,
>   `USERID` INTEGER
> );
>
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `CATID`, `USERID`)
> VALUES
>   ('70', '1', '1'),
>   ('70', '6', '1'),
>   ('70', '5', '1'),
>   ('71', '2', '1'),
>   ('72', '3', '1'),
>   ('72', '1', '2'),
>   ('72', '2', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID),USERID 
> FROM table1 
> GROUP BY USERID
> HAVING SUM((catid = 1) + (catid = 2) +(catid = 6)) = 3
> ```
>
> ```
> GROUP_CONCAT(ID) | USERID
> :--------------- | -----:
> 70,70,70,71,72   |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7264cba21760fd4944c41a4b31923ac)*

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the nested select:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users 
JOIN ON 
(
    SELECT * FROM categories 
    WHERE catdid IN (1,2,6)
) 
WHERE users.id = categories.id;
```